# How do I send a variable/flag to another thread in a non-blocking thread safe way in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I've been looking around and see some answers saying to use globals, but doesn't seem thread safe.  I have also tried using queues but that is apparently blocking, at least in how I did it.  Can someone help/show an example on how to launch a thread from the main thread and communicate between one thread to another in a non-blocking thread safe way?  Basically, the use case is that the threads will be looping and checking fairly constantly if there's something that needs to be done/changed and act accordingly.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Python Queues are thread safe according to the documentation. I don't think it should be a problem to push and pop from a shared queue within threads. https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: I can't seem to get the audio recording working when using queues.  I have gotten it working in a thread but can't seem to get this code working on a Raspberry Pi 4: https://pastebin.com/iNFN6Ek9 .  It throws a Errno -9981 Input Overflowed.  I'm pretty stuck trying to record audio while having the controls remain unblocked.  I have tried setting the buffer size to as high as 8192 to no avail as well.